# How to read from a database, add some of that information to html, and send that html to a user?

Tags: html, database

I'm designing a website where users can upload comments on pages, and other users should see those comments. I reached the stage where I have the comments stored in a database, and I know the place they're supposed to go in the html, and I need to connect those two things somehow.

I'm using express and Node.js on the server side, and postgres on the db side.

As of when I'm asking this, it seems to me it's very bad practice to have the user access the database. So I think the server needs to access the database based on the user's request, modify the generalized html's showing of comments to now have the information of the specific comments, save that to a file, and send it to the user. To do this I was thinking of creating an "html generator function" on the server-side that takes in specific comment information and puts it in the generalized html, but that seems like it doesn't scale well and I'm concerned that storing the intermediate file would be inefficient.

Is that the correct approach? Can you tell me known ways of doing this that aren't so hacky?

If you suggest using php, isn't there a problem where php connects to a server and disconnects every time we use it? I would prefer if the server connected once when it booted and did all the fetching when needed instead of connecting every time. It seems to me like that would involve far less overhead (correct me if I'm wrong...)

Comment: A "html generator" is usually known as "template engine". See [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) in Express.js documentation. The [Express.js tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction) at MDN puts templates, as well as database use, in context; it would be good to review it as well.

Comment: Well it should be called an html generator >:( thanks though!

Comment: Are template generators common practice? How else could you make a facebook or youtube?

Comment: Yes, using template engines to generate HTML from templates is extremely common. You can also hear the term "data binding engine", which is a step above — they work at clientside and let a template react in real time by modifying HTML dynamically to user actions. A different approach is to actually have a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) which describes a web page, which is then compiled; but this is minority, though it is used by some of the giants. I can rather confidently say that almost all serious websites use either templates or a web DSL.

Answer (score 0):

See the comment of Amadan for the full solution. It's called a "template engine"

Edit:
I highly recommend learning React. I learned EJS and it's difficult to scale. React is infinitely easier to program with for just a little more investment. The old web is much less declarative (& EJS is much less too).